# How to make the display go to sleep when screen is locked?

Tags: gnome, xorg, power-management, screensaver

I’m using a Debian amd64 install with the default GNOME desktop.  I’m aware that you can go into System | Preferences | Power Management, and choose to make the display go to sleep after a certain period of inactivity.  However, I currently have that set to ‘Never’ because until I lock the screen, I don’t want the display to go to sleep.  Once I lock the screen, though, I want it to go to sleep immediately unless/until it detects activity, or at least go to sleep after 1 minute or something.  Is there a way I can configure it to do this only when I ‘Lock Screen’?

Answer (score 6):

You could run a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
xset dpms force off
```

Bind this to a key sequence and whenever you lock your screen, the display will turn off.

Comment: Hmm, would there be a way to get such a script to run when the default ctrl-alt-L key sequence is pressed; or even when you select the 'lock screen' GNOME menu option?

Comment: In your Keyboard Preferences, change Lock to something else (eg., Ctrl-Shift-L) and map Ctrl-Alt-L to the script. You could edit the Menu entry the same way...

Comment: I tried `xset dpms force on` to force my CRT monitor never turn off, but it still does, any tip?